# Setting postgres logfile's timestamp to same as of local timezone

Tags: postgresql

I'm setting following parameters in postgres.sql

```
log_destination = 'stderr' 
logging_collector = on 
log_directory = '/DGlogs/Postgres_Logs'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%y_%m_%d_%T.log'
```

Say when current timestamp is Wed Apr 11 12:56:23 CDT 2018, the generated logile is in some other timezone (please see the timestamp in the file postgresql-18_04_11_17:51:28.log). It is showing as 17:51 which is not local timestamp. Even the contents of this file is also in different timezone as the filename.

```
[root@PGSQL Postgres_Logs]# date
Wed Apr 11 12:56:23 CDT 2018

[root@PGSQL Postgres_Logs]#
[root@PGSQL Postgres_Logs]# ls -ltr
total 10172
-rwxrwx--- 1 root     kodiakgroup  790537 Apr  9 18:59 postgresql-18_04_09_21:49:16.log
-rwxrwx--- 1 root     kodiakgroup 6327854 Apr 10 11:20 postgresql-18_04_10_00:00:00.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup 2819464 Apr 10 18:55 postgresql-18_04_10_16:28:41.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup  103011 Apr 10 18:59 postgresql-18_04_10_23:55:29.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup  244131 Apr 11 12:05 postgresql-18_04_11_00:15:56.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup   15335 Apr 11 12:09 postgresql-18_04_11_17:05:56.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup   15954 Apr 11 12:20 postgresql-18_04_11_17:09:14.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup   15835 Apr 11 12:33 postgresql-18_04_11_17:20:05.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup   16092 Apr 11 12:48 postgresql-18_04_11_17:39:16.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup   18018 Apr 11 12:51 postgresql-18_04_11_17:48:28.log
-rw------- 1 postgres kodiakgroup    8233 Apr 11 12:51 postgresql-18_04_11_17:51:28.log
```

How can I set the logfile's timestamp to same as of local timezone?

Comment: Really should be using UTC on your logs.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I set the logfile's timestamp to same as of local timezone?

By setting `log_timezone` in `postgresql.conf`. For a Debian-based OS, you may set:

```
log_timezone = 'localtime'
```

(this works because debian has a softlink `localtime` in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`).

On other systems that don't have this, I guess you would put the actual name of your local timezone, such as for instance `US/Central`.

Comment: That parameter doesn't  worked, getting following error while starting service.

Comment: Apr 16 18:22:05 PS1 postgres[13503]: [1-1] < 2018-04-16 12:52:05.757 GMT >LOG:  invalid value for parameter "log_timezone": "localtime"
Apr 16 18:22:05 PS1 pg_ctl: < 2018-04-16 12:52:05.757 GMT >LOG:  invalid value for parameter "log_timezone": "localtime"

Comment: @PratheejGC: it happens to work primarily on debian, please see edit